# Ubuntu Command line Extract part number and quantity from converted excel file

Tags: bash, command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have an excel file with 40 components and I converted (online) it to txt file for doing the command line functions. I want to extract part numbers (it is 6 or 7 digits number) from it. Some follow a specific pattern. I want to extract and save it in txt file
My code:

```
list.txt
        Product number 1  ac162049-2/slid||product|1971904|pgrid|119732683897|ptaid   1
        Product number 2, its accessories  1-82/pcrid|5194541117|pkw|product|3418376|-SHOPPING 10
        Product number 3  dip-40/dp/9761446       2
```

Expected output:

```
productnumber.txt
        1971904   
        3418376 
        9761446
```

My code:

```
grep -Po '/\K.[0-9]+[1-9]' hardware\ components_prashant.txt > serialnumber.txt
```

Present output:

```
9761446
```

Comment: You aren't giving *nearly* enough information about the rules of how you want the first column parsed.

Comment: @PaulHodges I have edited my question. My objective is extracting serial number only.

Comment: Yes, but it seems to be in column 4 in one record, column 5 in the next, and embedded in column 1 on the last. What are the *rules*?

Comment: @PaulHodges I converted the excel file to text. It could be due to gaps in the excel file, it converted like this. Is it possible to search `/` followed by `a number with 6 or 7 digits only`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it just any six-or-seven digits with non-alphanumerics before and behind?

```
grep -Eo '\b[0-9]{6,7}\b' productnumber.txt
1971904
3418376
9761446
```

In `-E`*xtended* pattern matching, `\b` is a "word boundary". c.f. [this tutorial](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). You could also use `\<` and `\>` as I did below.

`[...]` is a *character class* matching anything in the given set. a dash (`-`) indicates a range, so `[0-9]` is anything *from* zero *to* nine, inclusive. `{...}` specifies length limits, so `{6,7}` says a series of digits *no less than six, and no more than seven*.

If you wanted the fields you mentioned before, `(...)` is storage groupings, and `^` is negation in a character class, so:

```
sed -E 's/^ *([^0-9]+[0-9]+).*\<([0-9]{6,7})\>.* ([0-9]+) *$/\1|\2|\3/' productnumber.txt
Product number 1|1971904|1
Product number 2|3418376|10
Product number 3|9761446|2
```

Comment: Yes! it solved the problem. I have one more request: could you please elaborate on what each of the character in `-Eo \b[0-9]{6,7}\b` is doing. It helps me to understand what is going here.

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions. ;)

Comment: Just wow! the editing part where you answered the original question as well. I have to decode what `^ *([^0-9]+[0-9]+).*\<([0-9]{6,7})\>.* ([0-9]+) *$/\1|\2|\3/` each of these is doing here. I am curious, where do find all the possible combinations of searches like `[ ], { }, <, >, E` about all these?

Comment: I like the [GNU manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). Most of these apply everywhere.

Comment: Can you take a look at this question I created. I tried the solution after inspiring from your solutions here. There is small issue. This is what I tried `grep -Po '(product name argument)(number argument)(quantity argument)' rawfile.txt`. Looks like the issue is with first argument. The second and third yield results. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675230/extract-product-number-and-quantity-from-a-text-file

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your sample data, I believe the column delimiter is the pipe?

Assuming part number is column 1, QTY is column 8,  you can do this to get it out

`cat list.txt | awk -F| '{ print $1, $8 }' > quantity.txt`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the following error `        gawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum }' file
        gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
{ print $1, $8 }: command not found`

Comment: Can you clarify your comment? It looks like you got multiple commands bundled together without any clear separation.

Comment: I edited my question to avoid confusion.